# How to fetch data from java map in xslt

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I have a requirement ot get the data from Java map in XSLT.
I know using xalan I can implement it but we have a dependency on common Transformer which is forcing us to use Saxon-HE.
I am passing the java map to variable and getting it in XSLT.
Please advice how we can achieve that.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:param name="sequenceNbrMap" />

</xsl>
```

I need to get the value from this map based on dynamic key and this map is also dynamic so I can't directly create this map into XSLT.

Comment: Can you show us the Java code "passing the java map to variable"? Are you able to change that Java code to pass in some value Saxon on the XSLT side can deal with, like an `XdmValue`?

Answer (score 1):

Access to a Java map is only possible through extension functions, which have limited availability in Saxon-HE. Full information on Saxon extension functions can be found at

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility

Comment: Hi, Can you please share one example of how to access map from xslt? I am using saxon pe and my use case is same as above . Thanks

Comment: Things have moved on quite a bit since 2016; I suggest you ask a new question. Asking supplementary questions by way of a comment on an existing answer is never a good idea: there's no obvious place to answer the supplementary question.

One thing that's relevant is what Java object types the map actually contains.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay , I have sorted the problem using parse-json() function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom URIResolver and provide the map values as xml snippets.

```
class MapEntryResolver implements URIResolver
{

    private Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

    private static final String PREFIX = "map://";

    @Override
    public Source resolve(String href, String base)
            throws TransformerException
    {
        Source snippet = null;

        String key = href.replace(PREFIX, "");

        if(map.containsKey(key))
        {   
            snippet = new StreamSource(new StringReader("<" + key + ">" + map.get(key) + "</" + key + ">"));
        }

        return snippet;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String,String> map)
    {
        this.map = map;
    }

}
```

You can access the map values by using the document function in xslt.

```
<xsl:variable name="mapValue" select="document('map://foo')" />
```

Sample:

```
//First create the resolver
MapEntryResolver uriResolver = new MapEntryResolver();
//pass your map
uriResolver.setMap(yourMap);
//and attach it to the factory
TransformerFactory factory = new TransformerFactoryImpl(); 
factory.setURIResolver(uriResolver);
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(pathToYourXsl));
//start transform and store result
ByteArrayOutputstream result = new ByteArrayOutputstream();
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(pathToYourInputXml), new StreamResult(result));
```

The UriResolver creates xml snippets from your map data on demand like this:

```
<key>value</key>
```

In your xsl use the document function to get the snippets by providing the map key as parameter:

```
<!-- variable contains snippet <foo>bar</foo> -->
<xsl:variable name="mapValue" select="document('map://foo')" />
<!-- use it like any other doc-->
<xsl:value-of select="$mapValue/foo"/>
```

Comment: Feels hacky, but very clever!

Comment: I am new to XSLT process. Can you please bit explain here.I have an source xml so how can I append this xml map into source xml and your java code isn't creating any xml source from map.

Comment: I downvotet because its way too complex

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to access elements of a Java `Map` is to declare a namespace:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:map="java:java.util.Map" ... >
   <xsl:param name="sequenceNbrMap">
   <xsl:value-of select="map:get($sequenceNbrMap, 'keyInMap')"/>
   ...
```

Comment: Have you tested this with Saxon-HE? If I am reading the documentation correctly, calls to Java code require Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE. This question is expressly about Saxon-HE.