# Using map in xslt

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I'm trying to make a java call from xslt which will return a Map. Now i want to use this map in xslt for lookups. I'm using xslt1.0 and saxon processor. Saxon version used is 9.1.0.8

I was able to make the Java call and the value was stored in the map, but have no idea how to look this up in xslt.
Value which I get after printing the variable map is    {key1=value1,key2=value2......}

Sample Java code:

```
public static Map<String,String> createMap(){
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
         map.put("key"+I,"value"+i);
     }
    return map;
}
```

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="map">
       <!--Make Java Call Here-->
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="test">
               <!--Retrieve the value from variable map for key2-->
        </xsl:variable>
        <Output><xsl:value-of select="$test"/></Output>
        <!--Rest of xslt-->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output:

value2

Comment: So which version of Saxon exactly do you use, how does your Java code look?

Comment: If you're using Saxon, why would you want to use XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @Martin Honnen thanks for the response. Details have been updated in question. Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use a ten year old version of Saxon and can't move to an up-to-date release like Saxon 9.9 or 9.8? You still haven't shown how `<xsl:variable name="map"> <!--Make Java Call Here-->  </xsl:variable>` looks? Note that Saxon 9.8/9.9 support the XPath 3.1 data type system which has maps very similar to Java maps and therefore there is an easy conversion and an easy use of such maps, see similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/52968747/252228.

Comment: if you're stuck with old saxon versions, we used a workaround in the past... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272223/how-to-fetch-data-from-java-map-in-xslt/39290899#39290899